# Geocoding API reurning 'Zero results'

Tags: javascript, geocoding, axios, reverse-geocoding

i'm creating a project where i need to find the location of the user and show the nearby places like hospital, restaurant, etc. I'm testing this module using Geo-coding API and i'm using reverse Geo-coding to get human readable form from latitude and longitude. Also i'm using Axois to parse the json object. Here is my code:

```
<script>

// if user click allow location (get the latitude and longitude from the gps)
document.getElementById('alow').onclick = function() {
    var startPos;
    var lat ;
    var lon;

    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        // Do magic with location
        startPos = position;
        document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = 'latitude, longitude:';
        document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude.toFixed(6) + ", " + startPos.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);          
        reverserGeocode(startPos.coords.latitude.toFixed(6), startPos.coords.longitude.toFixed(6));
    };
    var geoError = function(error) {
        switch (error.code) {
        case error.UNKOWN_ERROR:
            console.log("Unknown error!");
            break;
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.log("Permission denied!");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            console.log("Position Unavailable!");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            console.log("Timeout!");
            break;
        }
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoError);
};

// if user enters location itself, get the location (City/State)
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {
    var location = document.getElementById('location').value;
    geocode(location);
};

function reverserGeocode(lat, lon) {
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
          latlng:lat+','+lon,
          key:'My_Api_key_here'
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);

        // format address
        if(response.data.results.length > 0) {
            var formatedAddress = response.data.results[0].formatted_address;
            document.getElementById('formattedAddress').innerHTML = formattedAddress;
        }else {
            console.log("From else statement: No address found at: " + lat + ", " + lon);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });       
}

</script>
```

here is the result from console:

```
{ 
  "results" : [], 
  "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" 
}
```

Also when i write the town/city name it returns proper json object. I pasted the latitude and longitude in google maps to get the location but it says "ZERO_RESULTS".
Thanks.

Comment: The `axios.get()` seems to be correct. [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/12rpyvfL/) try adding `console.log(lat+','+lon);` before you use `axios.get()`

Comment: lat and lon seem to provide  appropriate values.here is the generated url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=34.028547,74.821458&key=my-key-here